# Problem uploading files, access denied via cPanel, while not in FTP

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, uploading, virus

I have problem with uploading my files via cPanel but it works by FileZilla (FTP). It was said:

```
upload canceled: VIRUS DETECTED (Access Denied, ERROR).
```

I have tried uploading files via cPanel using Windows, Macintosh and Linux but return the same result.

How can this happen by using cPanel, while not in FileZilla?

Comment: Never found this issue. But you my check your files, is it corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

Please perform the following operation. You can try running a virus scan, seems to me cPanel is telling you the file is dirty, FileZilla doesn't check anything, it just does transfers, which is fairly unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

You can do check the things after removing the clamav connector on the cPanel server, you can simply do stop its services or can remove it with the help of below commands:

```
#/etc/init.d/clamd stop
```

or

```
#yum remove clamav*
```

Comment: It is never good advise to recommend that someone disable virus checking. Far better would be to recommend they check for viruses just in case.